# Vim and ack-grep: quickfix not opening files

Tags: vim, ack

I'm at a loss.

I'm running Debian Lenny, vim 7.3, and I've tried both ack-grep 1.80 and 1.96.  I added this line to my .vimrc:

```
let g:ackprg="ack-grep -H --nocolor --nogroup"
```

[When I include `--column` I get an error that it is not a valid option, that's why I tried upgrading ack-grep.]

When I execute `:Ack`, the quickfix window shows matches in this form:

```
|| folder/subfolder//file.rhtml:30:def do_it
```

I can use the `:cn`, `:cp`, etc. methods.  But I CANNOT get vim to open the files.  Both return and o do nothing.

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into the same issue on Ubuntu. To fix it I

- removed alias `ack` for `ack-grep`
- added this line to `.vimrc`:

`let g:ackprg = "ack-grep -H --nocolor --nogroup --column"`

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying your Vim from everything (all plugins and settings) except for the ones necessary for ack-vim. Does that help?

Comment: No, no change.  I still had to remove `--column` and then the non-behavior in the quickfix window is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the most recent version of ack.vim from github: https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim

I was running into the same issue and this fixed it for me.

See this issue for more information: https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/issues/36

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to escape the spaces.  If you look at the `g:ackprg` in plugin/ack.vim, it looks like this:

```
let g:ackprg="ack\\ -H\\ --nocolor\\ --nogroup"
```

Another solution would be to symlink your ack-grep to be ack to make up for the sadness of ack getting renamed ack-grep by your distro's packager. :-(

Comment: Sorry, this did not help.  My ack.vim does not have that escaping.  I've renamed ack-grep to ack, so no problem there.  When I ack from the command line, the --column option is parsed, no problem.